# I am getting an error while implementing Android Chat Bubbles

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am implementing chat bubbles in my app. in the main class I am getting an error in the setText line in the private class "mylistadapter" mentioned below.

```
tekst.setText(bubbleGreen.getMessages()); <-- line I am getting error
```

The error message is :
The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList)

In the Bubbles class I have used ArrayListgetMessages. I dont know how to fix this error while using ArrayList. Any tips would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Bubbles class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Bubbles {

private ArrayList<String> messages;
private int ikonId;

public Bubbles(ArrayList<String> messages, int ikonId){
    super();
    this.messages = messages;
    this.ikonId=ikonId;
}

public ArrayList<String> getMessages(){
    return messages;
}

public int getIkonId(){
    return ikonId;
}


}
```

Main Class:

```
private void setListAdapter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayAdapter<Bubbles> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Bubbles> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(XMPPChatDemoActivity.this, R.layout.list_row_layout_even, bubbles);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.list_row_layout_even, parent, false);
        }


        Bubbles bubbleGreen = bubbles.get(position);


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView
                .findViewById(R.id.even_bubble);
        imageView.setImageResource(bubbleGreen.getIkonId());

        TextView tekst = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text01);
        <<<tekst.setText(bubbleGreen.getMessages());>>>

        return itemView;
    }
}

private void bubblesList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    bubbles.add(new Bubbles(messages, R.drawable.bubble_green));
}
```

Comment: your adapter should be made of String not bubble and the dataset should be bubbles.getMessages(), or you should change the concept around your Bubbles class. From a container of messages it will be a message and then it should work

Comment: hello, I got two different suggestions now. Checking out both of them. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
tekst.setText(bubbleGreen.getMessages());
```

with

```
tekst.setText(bubbleGreen.getMessages().get(position));
```

and the error itself shows what's the problem is.

Comment: that's wrong. the adapter is made of bubbles. It could happens that the dataset contains more element of the ArratList of messages and the it will display less elements or more and the app will crashes with IndexOutBoundException

Comment: hello, I got two different suggestions now. Checking out both of them. Thank you for the suggestion both of you :) I am not so good in Arraylist so despite receiving the error message, couldnt fix it..

Comment: @blackbelt thanks for your comment... and as you said OP should consider redesigning his code...